# $("div").focusout is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-focusout

I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#Button1").click(function () {

        $("#divCompany1").slideToggle("fast");

    });

    $("divCompany1").focusout(function () {

        $("#divCompany1").slideUp("fast");

    });
});
```

Of which firefox reliably informs me:

> Error: $("div").focusout is not a
>   function Source File:
>   http://localhost:2546/user_area.aspx
>   Line: 456

I can't see anything obviously wrong both in my syntax and in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/), any ideas?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Comment: `focusout` was added in 1.4, as you can see in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: I guess that would explain it! I'll just add it now see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [function](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) is added on jQuery version 1.4. verify that you are using jquery version >= 1.4

Comment: Feel like an idiot now :-) teach me to read the docs properly